# How to make a function where it goes through given sets of tuples to see if it has a cycle effect?

Tags: python

I have an assignment where it ask to make a function where it goes through given sets of tuples to see if it has a cycle effect like in a game of dominos. For example given pairs [(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)], it would return True otherwise if the pairs were inputted like this [(2,3),(5,4)] it would return False. Essentially if the x value of the tuple pair after the first pair isn't the same as the y value of the first pair, it would return False.

Here's what I have so far but it only just checks the first pair of tuples to see if both the values match eachother.

```
 def domino_cycle(tiles):

   for (x,y) in tiles:

     if y == x:
       return True
     else:
       return False

 domino_cycle()
```

Comment: Hint: `for i in range(len(tiles) - 1): tile1=tiles[i]; tile2=tiles[i+1]`. Gives you two consecutive tiles at each loop. Then compare `tile1` and `tile2` according to your rules.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Thank you for the reply, just needed help to better understand what you explained here. why did you create two different variables for tile: til1 and tile2. still fairly new to programming, some concepts are still unclear to me. when you saif it gives me two concesutive tiles at each loop did you mean that it gives me a pair of tiles or 2 pairs (i.e (x,y),(x,y))

Comment: Creating the two variables was to show how you can reference the two consecutive tiles at each loop iteration.  You are right when you say `tile1` and `tile2` are tiles like `(x, y)`.  We subtract one in the range of the for-loop because we don't want to index passed the size of the tile list when we call `tiles[i+1]`

Comment: If you want to see better what's going on, add some print statements like `print(f"tile1: {tile1} --- tile2: {tile2}")` inside the for loop. You'll see the first and second, then second and third, then third and fourth, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Below

```
tiles1 = [(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
tiles2 = [(2,3),(3,24),(4,5)]

def is_domino_cycle(tiles):
  for idx,tile in enumerate(tiles):
     if idx > 0:
       if tile[0] == tiles[idx-1][1]:
         continue
       else:
         return False
  return True  

print(is_domino_cycle(tiles1))
print(is_domino_cycle(tiles2))
```

output

```
True
False
```